# Is this a valid triangulation of Moebius strip?

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation, mobius-band

This is a quick sanity check. I'd like to know if the diagram I've created is a valid triangulation of the Moebius strip or not.[image]

Comment: Seems alright to me. But you could've gotten away with just $a$ and $d$ is you wanted to. Of course, that would leave it unclear from the picture itself which two edges were glued together.